# Chrome v14 and v15 can't load jQuery. Says Failed to load resource

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-loader

I have a huge problem on my site. When I run it in Chrome v14 and Chrome v15 (through browserstack) it fails to load everything that I grab from Google libs. In the console it says:
`Failed to load resource. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js`

When I open this link in the browser (again through browserstack) I get the following error:

> The server presented a certificate that doesn't match built-in expectations. These expectations are included for certain, high-security web sites in order to protect you.

But when I open it in my normal browser I just get the jQuery minified library..

Comment: noone uses Chrome 14 anymore; current release is v29 and chrome is self-updating all the time.

Comment: since this is a problem with apparently newer SSL certificate used on an outdated browser, why don't you try another CDN to load it from, or host it yourself?